# Designing a java GUI program with user access control

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx, access-control

I want to make an application in java that has a GUI and a database. I will be using MYSQL as the database and my recent experience with JavaFX has been quite pleasant so that's what I'll be using to code.

My issue is I want user access control and want to show GUI components based on who or what type of user logs in.

So let us say it's a school management system and if a teacher logs in the teacher can access his or her course and homework assignments ( via GUI of course) but not any other teacher's. If an admin user logs in he/she can make changes to student profile, etc. but nothing else.

Could someone point me in the right direction with regards to concepts, tutorials, books, sample code, etc. so I can accomplish something like this

```
if(user==teacher){
    stage.setscene(teacherOnlyScene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Thank you so much! Apologies if its too subjective. This is the one site that I use like 90% of the time for answers to all my programming related questions.

Comment: Try looking into users, groups and roles. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your question is probably too large to be successfully answered here as you are asking about a fairly sizeable and potentially complex portion of the architecture of your final system. User access systems are generally quite complex especially if they are highly configurable e.g. you can grant users privileges outside their basic group privileges etc.

Before starting to write any code have a think about what you want to achieve. You've already come up with the idea of using user groups which I think is very sensible but there are some questions you need to ask. Can users belong to multiple groups? Can permissions be assigned to users or can they only be assigned to groups? Is the administrator a special case or can it be handled as just another group?

Have a look at the way Linux handles users and groups to assign permissions. It's a very well thought out system should offer some inspiration. Additionally the JavaEE 6 documentation orangegoat linked to provides a good overview of security in Java EE (but be warned it's fairly complex).

Having said that I feel I must encourage you to consider making this a web based application rather than using JavaFX. It doesn't sound like you have any particularly complex graphical requirements and it also sounds like you want multiple concurrent access to the system / database (e.g. more than one teacher can be checking their assignments at a time).

Perhaps I'm a little biased but I think a JavaEE based web application is a better match for these requirements. The business logic and most of the complexity of the multi-user side of things would be handled well by a bunch of [EJB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html)'s with all the persistence handled by [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html). The GUI would be written in [JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html) and [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) and the whole lot hosted on [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/). The real benefit of this set up is that you have a zero installation footprint which will save you a ton of time when rolling out new versions. Going the JavaEE route will probably make it more difficult for you but I feel it's the correct solution given the requirements.

Comment: WOW!I did not know about JSF till now. THANK YOU! And thanks again for the detailed answer.

And yes, I gave some thoughts to having it web-based but I guess I should have included who the target market is: Schools in third world countries with a few computers. They typically know how to surf, work with office programs and can generally go through a one click install.

I've reconsidered the database and I think its best to go with SQLite as asking non-technical folks to first install MySQL is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, that certainly changes things and I can see why you have gone for JavaFX. Have a look at using JavaDB rather than SQLite as it's already built into the JRE. 

You could still make it web based by using an embedded GlassFish instance (https://embedded-glassfish.java.net/) or shipping an installer that installs GlassFish and then deploys your application (Sonatype's Nexus is a good example IIRC). The benefit of this is you're ready to go when the school gets a network of machines as it surely will.

Comment: By the way, here's more context: The system will most likely be deployed in older machines (~5 years and older) with possibly pirated versions of Windows [I'm very familiar with the 3rd world]. I might switch the platform to linux for stability. The application will be very simple in the beginning- with a report or two here and there with the ability to show graphs of scores, admit students and staff. Simple. Is Glassfish still the way to go?

I don't mind difficulty for me. I can learn. So long as someone with some experience with clicking the mouse can use it.

Comment: I think 5 year old hardware would be able to cope (as long as it wasn't terrible when it was new). My development machine is 4 years old and runs a number of demanding web applications perfectly well. The real benefit to making it web based is not needing to rewrite a lot of it if (more likely when) the users want multiple simultaneous access. If you don't see that happening in the next few years then JavaFX may be a better choice as it's easier and quicker to pull together a decent user interface.

Comment: Yeah kinda torn now since PrimeFaces is just so awesome. Because it's Java I think I'll be able to reuse a lot of the code but PF does have better GUI and functionality for what I need.

I think I'll do it the Java EE way. Much better. I would have hated developing HTML tags and working the CSS out but with PF it'll be a breeze.

Comment: But time to deployment is a lot better with javafx. i'll stick to it. But Java EE is definitely in my radar now. Thanks much wobblycogs!